# Delay hovering effect

Tags: jquery, css

I have a grid and on every row of that grid there is button.When I click on that button a modal popup comes up.The popup has close button but as soon as I click that close button the hover effect on the row  on which that close button lies comes into picture.I want to delay this event.

The hover effect taking place is through CSS tr:hover and I cannot replace it I want as it is.I just want to delay hover effect when the close button is clicked.

Comment: Please provide some relevant code.....

Comment: Depends what the *effect* is and how you're creating it...

Answer (score 0):

use a setTimeout to delay the effect of hover, for example:

```
    var h;
    $("#row").mouseenter(function () {h = setTimeout(function(ev){//code that shows the hover text}, 1000)});
    $("#row").mouseleave(function () {clearTimeout(h);})
```

will delay hover for 1 second.  the mouseleave handler is to stop the text from showing if the user moved his mouse away before the 1 second was up.